# ImageView not rendering images over ~300 pixels on device

Tags: android, image, android-studio, imageview

I'm really struggling to get my app built in AndroidStudio to display any images that are larger in width or height than 300pixels on the device (Samsung galaxy tab 4 10" and galaxy note 4) they display fine in the android studio design view and all the other images in the app work fine, except for the 2 slightly bigger ones (being 1280x800 and 816x721).

This is a really odd bug as about 5% of the time on a clean and rebuild of the app one of them might appear.

I've tried cleaning,rebuilding,restarting AndroidStudio, various layouts,  all different sizes and scaling methods for the image view and no luck the only thing that seems to make the imageview's render is reducing the size of the image until they're under 300 pixels, at which point they are obviously too blurry.

Here is the source code for the layout xml of the splash screen which is displaying the 1280x800resolution image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com........SplashScreen">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loading_screen_image"
    android:src="@drawable/loadingscreen"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     />< /LinearLayout>
```

The activity class does nothing beyond start the next activity after 2 seconds, but I can post the code if people want to see it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to the `ImageView`.

Comment: seemingly a combination of adding this to all the layouts and then restarting the galaxy tab again has fixed the issue, thanks for the assist :)

Comment: You are welcome ... :)

Comment: did you find your answer? I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

This code worked on my project.